# Javascript matrix addition of an arbitrary number of arrays' values, without using array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, matrix, angularjs

I'm trying to build a helper function for my AngularJS app (but the solution doesn't have to use `angular.forEach`). The function should take an arbitrary number of arrays with same length and add the values together to form an new array, e.g.:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [4, 5, 6];
result = [5, 7, 9];
```

I'm trying to not use array.map() or [sylvesterjs](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) for IE8 compatibility. I'm stuck on looping through arguments as javascript doesn't seem to like nesting functions within a for loop. Code so far:

```
function arrayAdd () {
  // make sure all args have same length
  var totalLen = 0;
  angular.forEach(arguments, function (arg) {
    totalLen += arg.length;
  });
  var avgLen = totalLen / arguments.length;

  if (avgLen === arguments[0].length) {
    var arrNew = mkArray(0, arguments[0].length);
    // helper function to make an empty array, not shown here

    // need to refactor below with loop for unlimited # of args
    angular.forEach(arguments, function (arg, i) {
      arrNew[0] += arg[0];
    });
    angular.forEach(arguments, function (arg, i) {
      arrNew[1] += arg[1];
    });

    return arrNew;
  } else {
    throw 'arrayAdd expects args with equal length';
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for map, you only need to keep track of the arrays as you total them.

(This does not check that the arrays have the same length-)

```
  function sumArrayElements(){
        var arrays= arguments, results= [], 
        count= arrays[0].length, L= arrays.length, 
        sum, next= 0, i;
        while(next<count){
            sum= 0, i= 0;
            while(i<L){
                sum+= Number(arrays[i++][next]);
            }
            results[next++]= sum;
        }
        return results;
    }

var a= [1, 2, 3], b= [4, 5, 6], c= [1, 2, 3];
sumArrayElements(a, b, c)
/* returned value:(Array)
6, 9, 12
*/
```

Comment: This is a nice solution w/o any dependencies. Makes sense. Thanks. I need more practice looping in js. My other solution is slightly shorter but depend on AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add it to the array prototype if it doesn't exist?

```
if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.map= function(mapper, that /*opt*/) {
    var other= new Array(this.length);
    for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
        if (i in this)
            other[i]= mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this);
    return other;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. You have a good point. The solution didn't need array.map(). I was over-thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, didn't need array.map(). Writing the arrays and loops out on paper helped. Hope this is helpful for someone else.

```
function arrayAdd () {
  // ensure all args have same length
  var totalLen = 0;
  angular.forEach(arguments, function (arg) {
    totalLen += arg.length;
  });
  var difLen = arguments[0].length === totalLen / arguments.length;

  if (difLen) {
    var arrNew = mkYrArray(0, arguments[0].length, 0);
    // helper function to make an empty array, not shown here
    angular.forEach(arguments, function (arr, i1) {
      // each loop is an array from arguments
      angular.forEach(arr, function (arrValue, i2) {
        // each loop is a value from array
        arrNew[i2] += arrValue;
      });
    });
    return arrNew;
  } else {
    throw 'arrayAdd expects args w/ equal len';
  }
}
```

Comment: Trouble is, if you don't have map available, where did you get forEach?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS anyways with a very basic [forEach](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/angular.forEach) and IE8 support, but nothing for mapping arrays. Your answer is correct for being truly independent.