# Javascript operator overloading on lists

Tags: javascript

JavaScript does not support operator overloading. Matrix libraries in JavaScript could not simplify notation. I would like to create operator overloading with a simple trick by adding using syntax like z = x++y. This is not a valid statement in JavaScript.

That is why I would like to create an include method which will parse existing JavaScript files and replace those statements with actual JavaScript code. This is somehow related to coffescript where the compiler is inside JavaScript.  What would be the best way to approach that.

I have string manipulation solution:

```
"z=x++y;".replace(/(.*)=(.*)\+\+(.*)/i,"for(var _i_=0;_i_<$1.length;_i_++){ $1[i] = $2[i]+$3[i]}")
```

Example run:

```
for(var _i_=0;_i_<c.length;_i_++){ c[i] = data[0][i]+data[1][i];}
```

Obtaining Matlab, numpy like environment in JavaScript would be very convenient for easily deploying scientific models as web applications and avoiding computational burden in server side. Also, parallelization would be as easy as opening another browser tab from somewhere.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work when you could just use a function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324399/javascript-matrix-addition-of-an-arbitrary-number-of-arrays-values-without-usi

Comment: Yes, right for this specific case. But in general, I think I am looking for a language which will target client side scientific computing. Due to standardization limitations, I think javascript is the best candidate.

Comment: Use a [sweet.js readertable](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#binary-operators)? But I'd focus on all the other bits besides simple syntax extensions.

Comment: Maybe, I can start with those functions and then try to incorporate syntax later.

Comment: A python interpreter in javascript ! http://brython.info/